# How do I move the circle to the "WEST" border layout frame?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

This is file 1 (my instructor prefer's us to use separate files for each extension)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Lab2 extends JFrame {

Lab2(){
    setTitle("Lab 1b - Application #2");
    Lab2Panel p = new Lab2Panel();
    add(p);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Lab2 frame = new Lab2();
    frame.setTitle("Lab2 Application # 1");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(200, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

file 2:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Lab2Panel extends JPanel{
Lab2Button canvas = new Lab2Button();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

Lab2Panel () {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JButton leftButton = new JButton("left");
    JButton rightButton = new JButton("right");
    JButton upButton = new JButton("up");
    JButton downButton = new JButton("down");

    panel.add(leftButton);
    panel.add(rightButton);
    panel.add(upButton);
    panel.add(downButton);

    this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    leftButton.addActionListener(new Lab2MoveBallListener());
}


}
```

file 3:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Lab2Button extends JPanel {
int radius = 5;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawOval(getWidth() / 2 - radius, getHeight() / 2 - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

}

        public void moveLeft(){

            this.add(this, BorderLayout.WEST);
            this.repaint();
        }


}
```

the action listener code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Lab2MoveBallListener implements ActionListener{


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    this.moveLeft();
}
}
```

I am trying to move the circle to the WEST border layout when a user clicks the "left" button. Can someone help me please.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind not extending each class and only extending the actionlistener?

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance.  It is *necessary* to `implement` an `ActionListener`, the rest can be done in other ways.

Comment: I don't think I follow you. Thus far in class we have only created classes like this. When we need a button we write a class extending JButton and call an instance of that class.

Comment: *"When we need a button we write a class extending JButton and call an instance of that class."*  Do me a favor will you?  Smack the teacher upside the head and inform them that they are unfit for teaching OOD (or any code that requires it).  This general matter is worthy of a treatise, you will probably find many references to it on SO and about the net.  If you cannot figure it from your research, it might pay to ask a separate question.

Comment: @ Andrew Thomson see comments below your code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand what this GUI should be doing, but this works to move the circle to the left.  Points 3) & 4) of my comment still need to be addressed.

Here is the altered code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Lab2 extends JFrame {

Lab2(){
    setTitle("Lab 1b - Application #2");
    Lab2Panel p = new Lab2Panel();
    add(p);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Lab2 frame = new Lab2();
    frame.setTitle("Lab2 Application # 1");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(200, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class Lab2Panel extends JPanel{
Lab2Button canvas = new Lab2Button();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

Lab2Panel () {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JButton leftButton = new JButton("left");
    JButton rightButton = new JButton("right");
    JButton upButton = new JButton("up");
    JButton downButton = new JButton("down");

    panel.add(leftButton);
    panel.add(rightButton);
    panel.add(upButton);
    panel.add(downButton);

    this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    leftButton.addActionListener(new Lab2MoveBallListener(canvas));
}


}

class Lab2Button extends JPanel {
int radius = 5;
int x = -1;
int y = -1;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    if (x<0 || y<0) {
        x = getWidth() / 2 - radius;
        y = getHeight() / 2 - radius;
    }
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawOval(x,y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

}

        public void moveLeft(){

            //this.add(this, BorderLayout.WEST);
            x -= 5;
            this.repaint();
        }


}

class Lab2MoveBallListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab2Button canvas;

Lab2MoveBallListener(Lab2Button canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    canvas.moveLeft();
}
}
```

---

> ..how do I differentiate between buttons in the action performed?

There are a number of ways.

1. [`ActionEvent.getActionCommand()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand%28%29)/[`getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) with `if`/`else` statements to select the correct action.
2. Add a separate listener to each button.  This is more common in real world code.  No requirement for getting the source or inspecting the action command.

Comment: The assignment is for us to have a "ball" and move it across the screen when you click a particular button (left, right, up, down).

Comment: My thinking was that I could use BorderLayout to move the "ball" when you click the button in question.

Comment: This code is close to what I was thinking, but I need the "ball" to start in the CENTER pane.

Comment: Never mind the code does exactly what i needed thank you I am gonna go through and get an understanding of what you did thanks.

Comment: Where do I click to get +rep for this?

Comment: Okay this is what I need for the left button but when I try and code the right button how do I differentiate between buttons in the action performed?

Comment: BTW - the only thing the teacher seems to be doing right is recommending 'one class per source file'.  That ***is*** good design.  An SSCCE (like I posted), is about 'ease of use', rather than 'good design' specifically.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confused with the "this" keyword. The following might get you closer to what you want.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Lab2Panel extends JPanel
{
   Lab2Button canvas = new Lab2Button();
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();

   Lab2Panel () 
   {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      JButton leftButton = new JButton("left");
      JButton rightButton = new JButton("right");
      JButton upButton = new JButton("up");
      JButton downButton = new JButton("down");

      panel.add(leftButton);
      panel.add(rightButton);
      panel.add(upButton);
      panel.add(downButton);

      this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      leftButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
         {
             Lab2Panel.this.remove(canvas);
             Lab2Panel.this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.WEST);
             Lab2Panel.this.repaint();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: does Lab2Panel.this.remove(canvas) call the specific instance of canvas?

Comment: Yes, because canvas is a class scope variable in the Lab2Panel class. As far a given instance of a Lab2Panel class is concerned, there is only one "canvas", the one created in the Lab2Button canvas = new Lab2Button() line.

Answer (score 2):

this is what i suggested, hope it works for you.

Lab2.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Lab2 extends JFrame
{

    Lab2() 
    {
        setTitle("Lab 1b - Application #2");
        Lab2Panel p = new Lab2Panel();
        add(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Lab2 frame = new Lab2();
        frame.setTitle("lab2 Application # 1");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Lab2Panel.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Lab2Panel extends JPanel
{

    Lab2Button canvas = new Lab2Button();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    Lab2Panel()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton leftButton = new JButton("left");
        JButton rightButton = new JButton("right");
        JButton upButton = new JButton("up");
        JButton downButton = new JButton("down");

        panel.add(leftButton);
        panel.add(rightButton);
        panel.add(upButton);
        panel.add(downButton);

        this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        leftButton.addActionListener(new Lab2MoveBallListener(canvas));
        rightButton.addActionListener(new Lab2MoveBallListener(canvas));
        upButton.addActionListener(new Lab2MoveBallListener(canvas));
        downButton.addActionListener(new Lab2MoveBallListener(canvas));

    }

}
```

Lab2MoveBallListener.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Lab2MoveBallListener implements ActionListener
{
    private Lab2Button canvas;

    public Lab2MoveBallListener(Lab2Button canvas)
    {
        this.canvas = canvas;

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("left"))
        {
            canvas.moveLeft();
        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("right"))
        {
            canvas.moveRight();
        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("up"))
        {
            canvas.moveTop();           
        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("down")) 
        {
            canvas.moveDown();
        }

    }

}
```

Lab2Button.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Lab2Button extends JPanel
{
    int radius = 5;
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0) 
        {
            x = getWidth() / 2 - radius;
            y = getHeight() / 2 - radius;
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    }

    public void moveLeft()
    {
        x -= 5;
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void moveRight()
    {
        x += 5;
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void moveTop()
    {
        y -= 5;
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void moveDown()
    {
        y += 5;
        this.repaint();
    }

}
```